# Flatten, remove duplicates, and sort a list of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/3665278) I have a flattened list.

Now I want to remove duplicates and sort the list. Currently I have the following:

```
x = itertools.chain.from_iterable(results[env].values()) #From the linked answer
y = sorted(list(set(x)), key=lambda s:s.lower())
```

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? In my case x is of size ~32,000 and y ends up being of size ~1,100. What I have works, but I'd like to see if there's anything better (faster, more readable, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you just remove the list() which isn't needed, you've got a nice neat solution to your original problem. Your code is perfectly readable and efficient I think.

```
y = sorted(set(x), key=lambda s:s.lower())
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `results[env]` is a dictionary you can create a set of union values instead of flattening the values then sort the result:

```
>>> sorted(set().union(*results[env].values()), key=str.lower)
```

Also note that you don't need a `lambda` function as your key, you can simple use `str.lower` method.