# Sort and Print Nested String in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, printing

So here's my code. I separated the items in the list and printed them:

```
mylist = [["Orange", "Banana"], ["Grape", "Orange", "Apple"]]

for s in mylist:
print '\n'.join(s)

Orange
Banana
Apple
Grape
Orange
```

But I want the list alphabetized. I've tried this, but it only sorts the items within their nests:

```
for s in mylist:
print '\n'.join(sorted(s))

Banana
Orange
Apple
Grape
Orange
```

How do you print and sort items in a nested list all together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten, remove duplicates, and sort a list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582889/flatten-remove-duplicates-and-sort-a-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: zip the nested lists together first:)

Comment: @Jason, zip is not the correct function.

Comment: @SumnerEvans not that one, no duplicate removal needed. cannot find a suitable one, but that's a very simple question indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's combining flattening and sorting. Flattening is handled in various ways here: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-). Sorting is built-in.

My version:

chain using `itertools.chain` *then* sort:

```
import itertools

for i in sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist)):
    print(i)
```

Or without `itertools`, generate a list comprehension (which has the benefit of passing a `list` to `sorted` so `sorted` doesn't need to force iteration):

```
for i in sorted([x for sl in mylist for x in sl]):
    print(i)
```

(the most efficient way would probably be `sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist)))`, though)

Comment: No need for the inner list comprehension on the second option. `sorted` can accept a generator expression: `sorted(x for sl in mylist for x in sl)`

Comment: no need but it is faster because else `sorted` has to iterate to build a list anyway and iteration is slow.